# Finding a basis for a polynomial vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

I came across the following question:

Let $V$ be the real vector space of polynomials with degree $\le 2$. For $\alpha,\beta \in \mathbb{R}$ let $W_\alpha = \{f \in V |f(\alpha) = 0\}$ and $D_\beta = \{f \in V |f'(\beta) = 0\}$. $f'$ describes the derivative of $f$.

Find a basis for $W_\alpha$ and $D_\beta$.

Unfortunatly I am not quite getting my head wrapped around vector spaces with polynomials yet. So after failing the question I had a look at the solution and there it says:

*By solving the system of linear equations:*

$W_\alpha: \{X-\alpha, X^2-\alpha^2\}$

$D_\beta: \{1, X^2-2\beta X\}$

More explanation is not given.

I know that the elements in $W_\alpha$ in the form of $f(x) = c_2X^2+c_1X+c_0$ are zero at $\alpha$, so $f(\alpha) = c_2\alpha^2+c_1\alpha+c_0 = 0$.

Respectively for the elements in $D_\beta$: $f'(\beta) = 2c_2\beta+c_1 = 0$.

However, it is not clear to me how I get from that information to the basis of $W_\alpha$ and $D_\beta$ using systems of linear equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for $W$ form the condition

- $f(\alpha) = c_2\alpha^2+c_1\alpha+c_0 = 0\implies c_0=-c_2\alpha^2-c_1\alpha$

we obtain

- $f(x) = c_2X^2+c_1X-c_2\alpha^2-c_1\alpha=c_2(X^2-\alpha^2)+c_1(X-\alpha)$

can you proceed for $D$?

Comment: Oh I see. $f'(\beta) = 2c_2 \beta + c_1 = 0 \implies c_1 = -2c_2\beta \implies c_2X^2+c_1X+c_0 = c_2X^2-2c_2\beta X+c_0 = c_2(X^2-2\beta X) + c_0 ( 1)$. Thank you! I also saw Gaussian normal form mentioned somewhere in the solution. Basically as I wrote in the question (I left it out because I thought it was not important): *Since the system is already in Gaussian normal form, by solving the system of linear equations: ....*. Do you have any idea how that can be related to this question?

Comment: @Bobface in this case it doesn't seem necessary, how was it mentioned exactly?

Comment: Unfortunatly it was exactly mentioned as I wrote it. I think it means transforming the formula for $f$ into a system of linear equations with 2 rows containing only zeroes. But again, I dont know how to continue from there.

Comment: @Bobface I can't say at the moment, maybe it is simple referring to the fact that the subspace is in the form $c_2(X^2-\alpha^2)+c_1(X-\alpha)$ thus the basis can be easily found.